# Fundamental group of infinite row of tori

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Consider a family $ \lbrace T_i \rbrace_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} $ of tori indexed on the integers such that every torus is attached to the preceding one and to the subsequent by a single point. How can we compute the fundamental group of this infinite row of tori?

I want to stress the fact that «every torus is attached to the preceding one and to the subsequent by a single point» therefore, this is not a duplicate of the question  [Fundamental Group is free on infinite generators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082073/fundamental-group-is-free-on-infinite-generators)

Comment: The question linked as a possible duplicate is in fact a different question.

Comment: I'm nominating this question to be re-opened, since it is not the same as the other question.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental group is the free product of the groups $\pi_1(T_i)$ for $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so it is isomorphic to a free product of countably infinite copies of the group $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

To show this, the first step is to show that the fundamental group of the union of the tori $T_i$ for $-n \le i \le n$ is the free product of $\pi_1(T_i)$ for $-n \le i \le n$, and this is done by induction using Van Kampen's theorem. The second step is done just using a direct limit argument.

Comment: Do you know if the direct limit argument is necessary? This argument feels natural, but there's this conflict between the surface being noncompact and having finitely many compact loops generating the group that I feel could be exploited without having to use the machinery of Van Kampen or direct limits.

Comment: There's a few misconceptions in your comment. First, the space is not a surface, because a point where two toruses touch each other has no neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Second, this surface does not have finitely many compact loops generating the group, in fact the fundamental group of this space is infinitely generated. @SantanaAfton

Comment: Regarding machinery, if you understand the proofs underlying those machines, you can just carry out those proof ideas directly if you like. But that's why we have theorems, so that you don't have to keep repeating the same details of proof every time you have a similar calculation to do. In the case of the direct limit argument, the underlying proof idea is that each loop, being compact, touches only finitely many of the toruses; and each loop homotopy, being compact, also touches only finitely many of the toruses.