# Surface of infinite genus deformation retracts onto a graph

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, surfaces

[image: facenter image description here]

This is an exercise in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. There is a solution in this link: [Fundamental Group of surface with infinite genus is free on infinite generators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082073/fundamental-group-of-surface-with-infinite-genus-is-free-on-infinite-generators), which uses the van Kampen theorem.

However the question says that compute the fundamental group of the surface by showing that it deformation retracts onto a graph, so I want to use this approach. But I can't see how does this surface deformation retracts onto a graph. What graph should the surface deformation retracts onto?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but don't you need to "puncture" the surface to deformation retract it to a countably infinite wedge of spheres (one for each hole in the surface)?

Comment: I guess it would not strictly be an infinite wedge of circles but something like the real line with a circle attached at each integer point.

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces/92723#92723) is a link to my MathOverflow answer to the generalized question: every noncompact (connected) surface deformation retracts to a graph.

Answer (score 1):

There are some choices, but Frederik is right. One graph is a line connecting an infinite number of circles. Draw a circle about each hole and then connect them with lines running from each circle to the next. Ascii art:
$$\cdots\text{ -o-o-o-o-o- }\cdots$$
The surface can be deformed to this graph. First squeeze between each hole to a tube about the line. Each hole squeezes to a torus about the circle. So you have a sequence of toruses connected by tubes. Continue to shrink the tube diameters and torus minor diameter to $0$, and you end up with the infinite connected circles graph. A little further deformation gets you the circles linked to the line as described by Frederik. For example, the union of the $x$-axis and circles of radius $\frac 13$ centered around $\left(n, \frac13\right)$ for each $n \in \Bbb Z$.